# Reading GitLab GL_REPOSITORY environment variable

Tags: git, environment-variables, gitlab, githooks

I'm creating a server side hook (pre-receive) on GitLab 9.5. I need to know what repo is updated by push command.

The command `echo $GL_REPOSITORY` is executed by hook, but returns blank/empty on output. My hook was edited in a shell script.

These are my questions:
How can I read this environment variable?
Is there some configuration needed on the GitLab server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the script does not able get anything from `echo $GL_REPOSITORY`, that means that that variable is not present in the environment anymore. To add it, Please add this in the `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export $GL_REPOSITORY=<Value Here>
```

And now make that to system by using `source ~/.bashrc`. Now you can be able to get that variable in your script.